# Python Pandas Merge --- which rows are not merged?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

There might be former questions but they do not show up when you search for them.
This question and its title is very informative.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'x1': [1, 2, 3], 'x2': [11, 22, 33]})
                    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'bazz'], 'y1': [1, 2, 3], 'y2': [111, 222, 333]})

merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how= 'inner', left_on=['lkey','x1'], right_on=['rkey','y1'])

merged_df
```

How to show which rows of df1 are not merged?

Listing unmerged rows of df1 with columns '**lkey**' and '**x1**' will be very helpful.

```
 baz   3
```

Comment: `indicator=True` see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney indicator=True only adds one more column as _merged but does not show the rows of df1 that are not merged.

Comment: `dfm = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['lkey','x1'], right_on=['rkey','y1'], indicator=True)` then `dfm[dfm._merge == 'right_only']`, as in the 1st duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check if the df `.isin` the `merged_df` dataframe and then pass as a boolean series with `~` to return the rows that were not merged:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'x1': [1, 2, 3], 'x2': [11, 22, 33]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'bazz'], 'y1': [1, 2, 3], 'y2': [111, 222, 333]})
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how= 'inner', left_on=['lkey','x1'], right_on=['rkey','y1'])
df1[~df1.isin(merged_df)].dropna()
Out[1]: 
  lkey   x1    x2
2  baz  3.0  33.0
```

You could also do an `outer` merge and check with `indicator=True` per Trenton's comment or simply dropna on a subset of `lkey` with:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how= 'outer', left_on=['lkey','x1'], right_on=['rkey','y1']).dropna(subset=['lkey'])
```